# Rolling back a deletion to handle a server error in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

We have an Ember.js application which uses Ember Data. We are trying to do the following:

1. Delete a record.
2. If there is a server error (due to the fact that the application can have a "locked" state where records can not be deleted), roll the record back to its previous state, prompt the user to unlock app, and continue.
3. If there is no server error, continue as normal.

We have found that this does not work

```
object.destroyRecord().then ->
  # handle success
, (reason)->
  object.rollback()
  # prompt for the unlock
```

In both cases, we see an error that looks like:

```
Error: Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object
```

But it isn't clear how to remove the `isDestroyed` state once it has been set.

In general, it seems that, in either case, once we call `destroyRecord`, there is no way to rollback the changes to a pre-deleted state once, even if there is a server error.

Comment: Haven't used Ember data in a while as I got frustrated with it but I saw this thread on the forums.  Not sure if you've seen it or if it's related to your issue but might be worth a read: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/expected-behaviour-of-rollback-after-save-attempt-returns-422-ember-data-1-0/2513/15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that you need to put the rollback call in becameError() function.

```
// Overwrite default destroyRecord
destroyRecord: function () {
    this.deleteRecord();
    this.save().then(
        function (){
            //Success
        },
        function () {
            //Failure
        }
    );
},

becameError: function (item) {
    this.rollback();
}
```

The item will disappear from views until the server returns the error and then magically reappear.

Answer (score 1):

Try [deleteRecord](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_deleteRecord), followed by save. The docs explicitly state that this allows you to rollback on error.

```
  object.deleteRecord()
  object.save().then( ->
     # handle success
  , (reason) ->
     object.rollback()
  )
```

Comment: Tried that too with the same result.  We can rollback a delete *before* calling save.  But once save is called and the server returns an error, there does not seem to be a straightforward way to restore the object.

Comment: Hmm, the docs seem a bit misleading then. Maybe it's worth clarifying as an issue on the ember-data repo?